# setting textview to the string passed from another activity

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I have an edittext in first activity **(apples.java)**. User can write anything using edittext which is passed as a string to second activity **(Bacon.java)** on clicking a button. Second activity has a textview written *Bacon*. When a string is passed from first activity, *Bacon* is replaced with the passed string/text.
**What is happening :** When nothing is written using editText and button is clicked to go to second activity, Bacon disappears.
**My requirment is that if nothing is passed using EditText and only button is clicked, Bacon should not get replaced.If something is passed, it should replace Bacon.**

**apples.java**:

```
Intent i = new Intent(apples.this,Bacon.class);
final EditText applesInput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.applesInput);
String userMessage = applesInput.getText().toString();
i.putExtra("applesMessage",userMessage);
startActivity(i);
```

**Bacon.java**

```
final TextView baconText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.baconText);

Bundle applesData = getIntent().getExtras();
if(applesData==null){
    Toast.makeText(Bacon.this, "Love u", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    return;
}
String applesMessage = applesData.getString("applesMessage");
baconText.setText(applesMessage);
```

[This is first activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VUOgN.jpg)

[This is second activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yGHyK.jpg)

Comment: Just check if applesMessage is empty using `TextUtils.isEmpty(applesMessage)` and set it or not based on the result

Answer (score 1):

Do this:

```
if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(applesMessage))    
    baconText.setText(applesMessage);
```

Answer (score 0):

In **apples.java** write `if(applesInput.getText().toString().equals(""); { i.putExtra("applesMessage",userMessage);}` just add this..

Answer (score 0):

your problem is that Bundle is not null, so the condition is never satisfied.no string is set **does not** mean that your bundle is Null

**change it to**

```
 final TextView baconText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.baconText);

    Bundle applesData = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(applesData!=null){
     String applesMessage =applesData.getStrng("applesMessage")
     if(applesMessage ==null ||applesMessage .trim().equals("")){ //trim to delete spaces 
        Toast.makeText(Bacon.this, "Love u", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
        return;
           }

    baconText.setText(applesMessage);
    }

}
```